# PIC - 4-20mA (Duty cycle formula)

Tags: pic, pwm, c

I am implementing a 4-20mA current loop to my PIC. I have everything working. I am measuring the distance away from an object. When I hardcoded the distance as 300 the output voltage is 4V and when the distance is 12cm the output voltage is 0.8V. These values are got because the current needs to be 200uA before it enters the current loop. The current loop has a gain of 100, therefore giving 20mA on the output. The resistor I use is 20K.

(300cm) \$ Current = \dfrac{4}{20K} = 200uA \times 100 = 20mA \$

(12cm) \$ Current = \dfrac{0.8}{20K} = 40uA \times 100 = 4mA \$

The problem is I have to work out a formula for the duty cycle to get these values. The formula I am using is D.C = \$ 300 \times 2.2 + 158 = 818 \$ which gives 4V but if i substitute 12 for 300 I get 184 which does not correspond to 0.8V which is what I need. Can anyone help on this, if I am going about the wrong way or what way I need to approach this. Thank you

http://cr4.globalspec.com/PostImages/201012/4-20mA_LT1013_XTR115_3EA2C958-E757-2953-041770EF1E1B4760.jpg

Comment: how did you get this formula? What is it based on? And to clarify it for me: You need a formula that gives a 10 bit number that you can use for your PWM?

Comment: I added a link. R3 is 20K if Vin is 4V that gives 200uA with a current gain of 100 will give 20mA

Comment: Do you have a link for the datasheet for your proximity sensor? Your system is probably not linear, that is why your formula doesn't work.

Comment: Ya sure here it is http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/xtr116.pdf

Comment: Sorry misread the question no I dont have a datasheet. How do i fix that problem if the system is not linear. Thanks for the help

Comment: Works absolutely perfect @Spehro Pefhany. Thank you very much. Could you provide a link or anything for how to do this. Just dont understand how you were able to manipulate these numbers. Once again thank you.

Comment: @Gooner1990 you should probably put that comment to his answer, not commenting on your own question

Comment: @Gooner1990 also, he uses the standard line question y = mx+c and uses some common sense and logic for the 10-bit PWM values and the reference voltage to give you nice and easy to understand numbers.

Comment: @KyranF, I am guessing Gooner1990 does not have enough rep to comment on other answers.

Comment: @r_ahlskog no, you do not need any rep to comment on answers to your own question, you need 30+ to comment on other questions and their answers though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your one data point, that 818 gives you 4V, I can apply some detective work and surmise that you are using the PWM in 10-bit mode and your supply / PWM reference voltage is 5V.

---

Edit: That means that the output voltage after low-pass filtering is

Vout = Vref * count/1024

so count must be 1024 * Vout/Vref.

Count for 4V (20mA full scale @ 300cm in) is 819.

Count for 0.8V (4mA minimum scale @ 12cm in) is 164.

---

Edit: So start by determining the multiplier for the 'gain'- change in count for change in input cm. We call the change in input or output of an instrument from one extreme to the other the 'span'. Since this is linear we can ignore the zero intercept for now and calculate the slope- we'll add or subtract a number later to get the 'zero' right.

The span of your output voltage must be 4-0.8V = 3.2V for an input change of (300-12) = 288cm, which corresponds to a count span of 819 (at 20mA out or 300cm in) - 164 (at 4mA out or 12cm in) = 655 counts.

(You had 818 corresponding to 654 counts which might be because your 5V Vref is a touch higher than 5V).

So the multiplier must be 654 or 655 divided by the input change 288 = 2.274.

Now correct the zero intercept:

At 12cm you desire an output voltage of 0.8V, or a count of 164. If we multiply 12 * 2.274 we get 27 counts, which is short of the desired 164 counts by 137 counts, so add 137 to the result.

So, if x is the number of cm, you must multiply it by 654/288 = 137/144 (or 655/288 with exact 5V Vref) and add 137.

12 cm would thus give you 164 counts for 0.802V and 300cm would give you 818 counts for 3.994V (or 819 for 3.999V).

Note that 16 bit integer multiplication is inadequate to multiply 137 x 300 without overflow, but if you're using floating point, no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and explanation greatly apreciated